# How to define a well made message class in C++

Tags: c++

At the moment I am working on a message class in C++ for data communication, e.g. over a serial port. For this question let's say I have two different messages (I do have more), e.g. a gyroscope- and a acceleration message both with calibration data and sensor values. Since I am an engineer who learned C++ for himself I had a look at my favorite C++ book and figured out that it might be useful to use a factory pattern for the message.

So a simplified version of my header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H
#include <cstddef>

class message
{
public:

/**
 * \brief ~message:
 *        Virtual destructor of the class message.
 */
virtual ~message();

/**
 * \brief getMessage:
 *        Creates a message (with new).
 *
 * \param[in] size  Size of the dataArray.
 * \param[in] data  Bytearray of the message.
 *
 * \return If messagetype in the Array data eqal to 0 => new GyroMessage.
 *         If messagetype in the Array data eqal to 1 => new AccelMessage.
 *         Else => new NotValidMessage.
 *
 */
static message* getMessage(size_t size, char* data);

protected:

/**
 * \brief message:
 *        Default konstructor of the class message.
 *
 * \param[in] size  Size of the dataArray.
 * \param[in] data  Bytearray of the message.
 *
 */
message(size_t size, char* data);

/// Size of the dataArray.
int size;
/// Bytearray of the message.
char* dataArray;
/// Type of message.
char messagetype;
};

#endif // MESSAGE_H
```

The clases `GyroMessage`, `AccelMessage` and `NotValidMessage` are child classes of `message`. There are two things I do not like about this pattern:

First: If I want to add a new message, it is now enough to add a new class which is inherited form `message`, you have to add another if statement is in the static function `getMessage`.

Second: If I want to use the data e.g. from the `GyroMessage`, I have to `reinterpret_cast` the message.

Is there a better pattern that I could use for this purpose?

Comment: Stay away from patterns and look up "serialization".

Comment: @Blacktempel No! This is a minimized pattern, not actual code in use. We can't review this. Please take a look at the [Code Review help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you have to use `reinterpret_cast` something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Two questions.  Why do you have to reinterpret_cast --  How is polymorphism insufficient here?  Second, why do you have a member variable for the message type, if there will be a different class for each message type?

Comment: BTW I think that a factory function is a perfectly fine solution here.  I have used it in similar situations.  Hopefully we can address the issues you have with it to improve the soluction.

Comment: @Basya: Let's say I get a bytearray with a valid gyromessage over the serial port. By using the function getMessage(...) I get an object of the type message. But what I want to have ist the gyromessage. Since I know the message is of the type gyromessage form the value of the member messagetype I can use reinterpret_cast. 

I know this solution is ugly, that's why I am asking for a better solution.

Comment: The question is what is the difference in the *interface* between a gyromessage and an accelmessage?  If the interface can be similar enough, with the *implementation* handling the differences, then you can keep using the base class pointer and you don't have to cast.  Alternatively, you create a message *of a certain type* in the first place -- if you don't want to work generically via the base class pointer, you don't necessarily need a factory function.  Just create what you want in the first place.

Comment: For the part of creating and reading a message the implementation is handling the differences. But when I come to the use of the data I need to know wether it is a gyromessage or accelmessage. And what happens if I create a gyromessage form data that belongs to a accelmessage? I just get a char -array over my serial port an the size.

Comment: So how do you know which kind of message to create?

Comment: In getMessage(...) I disassemble the dataArray: 
First i read the size an checksum from the dataArray which is also part of the dataArray. If both the size and checksum are equal to the size and checksum of the dataArray i can read the messagetype form the dataArray. Depending on the value I create a gyromessage,  a accelmessage or a notvalidmessage.

Comment: I guess in that case I would make an analyze function to determine which type it is, and then specifically instantiate that.  Anyway, how did you know to what type to cast it?  And, thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A factory function is an excellent solution when you want to work generically, with knowledge of which type to create either inferred or known only at the point of creation.

If you know what type you want to create, and you are planning to use the created class with a pointer to the specific, derived type (using its specific interface) then you do not need a factory function.  Create what you need and use it!  In that case, you need a base class only for common functionality and/or for passing to specific functions which work on all derived types generically.

Alternatively, if you do want to work generically, then you can use a factory function and *not* cast the result.  Work with a pointer to the base class.  Have a common interface and handle the differences internally.  If you can not do this, then your scenario is not a candidate for this approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure my ideas are good but it costs nothing sharing.

I've done something similar few days ago for Arduino, and for my case I made this choices:

- for me the data payload is a `pod` (plain old data) struct where the compiler is informed to pack it. To achieve so I used a `define` that handles the compiler directive to pack it (for `g++` is `__attribute__((packed))`)
- the class in my case handles almost everything, thus I written it with a template. The template is for the payload struct
- for sending the message in byte array I used a templated `union` inside the class. You have to check the byte ordering of the sender and receiver if you use this method. Something like that:

  ```
  template <class P>
    union Packet {
    P data;
    unsigned char buff[sizeof(P)];
  }
  ```

  My toolchain supports template so I used them. But you can use more template to insert more packages inside the same union. You need only to remember to have a common field in all the struct that identifies the kind of package (see below).
- my class does not handles reading and writing, but instead requires the user of the class to provide 2 callbacks for reading and writing that accepts as arguments the buffer itself, the dimension of the buffer and a void pointer for user data. I think this is a good way to make the class agnostic with respect to the transmission channel.

The example (I'm simplifying **a lot**):

```
template <class A, class B,  std::size_t N>
union Packet {
  A a;
  B b;
  unsigned char buffer[N];
};

#define PAYLOAD(X, Y) struct X \
  Y __attribute__((packed));   \
  typedef struct X X;

template <class A, class B, std::size_t N>
class Message {
   union Packet<A, B, N> packet;

   // [...]
}

// [...]

// Time to declare you messages
PAYLOAD(GyroMessage, { char type; float x; float y; })
PAYLOAD(AccelMessage, { char type; float x; float y; float z; })
// GyroMessage will always have type = 0x01 and
// AccelMessage will always have type = 0x02 for example

// you know that sizeof(AccelMessage) > sizeof(GyroMessage)
// there is for sure a way to automatize this thing at 
// compilation time through macros. 
// Time to declare the class
Message<GyroMessage, AccelMessage, sizeof(AccelMessage)> message;
```

To retrieve the correct value you can still (through the union) access the value that you want, without adding new particular functions. But at the moment I don't have a very *nice* way to access them programmatically.

**Those are only some hints, I really don't know what you are doing or which are your priority. So take them with caution.**